# Addition of DISTINCT clause in SQL returning wrong values

Tags: sql, performance, vba, excel

A bit of background: I'm working for an organization with a large number of users running reports in excel. Often they require macros which compare two sets of data against each other. A large portion of my work involves tuning specific change report macros. Not pretty, but it pays the bills.

I had an idea today to pull excel tables into an ADODB object in vba and then run SQL against the object. Everything seemed to work well... but then I came across odd behavior.

This returns all the names in table1 where a.Name isn't in table2. And it works fine, but some of the names come up multiple times.

```
SELECT a.Name FROM [Table1] AS a
LEFT JOIN [Table2] AS b
ON a.Name = b.Name
WHERE b.Name IS NULL
```

Adding a DISTNCT clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Name FROM [Table1] AS a
LEFT JOIN [Table2] AS b
ON a.Name = b.Name
WHERE b.Name IS NULL
```

Completely changes which names appear. What shows up is DISTINCT, but present in both tables.

I tried rewording it a s a GROUP BY to replace the distinct value and recieved the same results. I checked with the local guru and got no where. Next step is to install a real database here to run some tests on.

I'm perplexed though.

Comment: I've tried both SQL statements on some simple tables in Excel and get correct output from both. The only difference is that DISTINCT suppresses duplicate rows as you would expect. In your ADO connection definition, have you used IMEX=1 to allow for mixed data types?

Comment: @sten . . . It is just returning the names in a different order.  If you want results in a particular order, you need an `order by` clause.

Comment: @barrowc I should note that I tried this with a small set of values and got the correct answer. The production set was over 10's of thousands of rows. Again it works without distinct on any set, and with distinct produces other results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This question is not about the order of the results. Different results are being returned. If there's something I can add to improve clarity let me know. I will when I log back in.

Comment: If you happen to have more than 65,536 rows, are you using the correct Excel 2007 onwards connection string (where the provider is "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0")? If you use the older Excel 2003 connection string (with provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0") for worksheets with more than 65K rows then problems tend to arise

Comment: @barrowc No it is Jet. That might be it, I'll check that out tomorrow morning. It's well over 65k rows.

Comment: @barrowc That was it, spot on buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> If you happen to have more than 65,536 rows, are you using the correct Excel 2007 onwards connection string (where the provider is "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0")? If you use the older Excel 2003 connection string (with provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0") for worksheets with more than 65K rows then problems tend to arise–  barrowc

barrowc nailed it. It was the old connection string causing the issue. Since I had more than 64k rows of data the output was behaving strangely. Swapping the Jet string for "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad that worked. For future reference, full connection string details are at [http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work with an ADODB object in vba, but I would do something like the following in SQL Server of MySQL ...

If I read your question right, you're trying to find names from table A that aren't in table B.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Name 
FROM [Table1] AS a
WHERE a.Name not in (
           SELECT b.Name
           FROM [Table2] AS b
      )
```

Comment: I tried a variant of this, I'll do it again tomorrow maybe I didn't do it correctly the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Use outer join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Name FROM [Table1] AS a
LEFT outer JOIN [Table2] AS b
ON a.Name = b.Name
WHERE b.Name IS NULL
```

Comment: Outer isn't a valid keyword in this case. ADODB didn't take it.